# how to print 2D matrix with some constraints?

Tags: python, matrix, 2d

I've to print nXn matrix with 0's and 1's the condition is we know number of 1's in first row, second row, nth row as well as we know number of 1's in first column, second column,... nth column.

ex:

```
n=3

rows=[2, 0, 1]   # in first row 2 one's, second row 0 one's    
cols=[1, 0, 2]   # in first col 1 one's, second col 0 one's
```

**final matrix** be like

```
1 0 1

0 0 0

0 0 1
```

can anyone suggest me the logic how to print?

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of the question though I do not suppose it is possible. If we are to take a look at the matrix with

```
rows=[2, 1, 1, 2]    
cols=[2, 1, 1, 2]
```

it could result:

```
1 0 0 1
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
1 0 0 1
```

but it could also result:

```
1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 1
```